# Passing command as input to diff command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, diff

I am trying to compare the file system states of a server, and I am storing the benchmark (initial state) in one `initialSnapshot.log` file. And now I am trying to compare it with runtime data , so I can echo any change in file stats.

```
#Capture the filesystem stats at the start and store them in initialSnapShot.log file.

find storage1 -type f -ls > initialSnapShot.log

#While loop to keep continues check on stats. 

while true
do
    #Below command does not work
   diff --suppress-common-lines -y `find storage1 -type f -ls` initialSnapShot.log


done
```

However, it does not work as per plan

```
diff: invalid option -- -
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

Please suggest any better design approach ? Shall I store the output of find inside second file(Seems dirty) ?

Edit:

```
find storage1 -type f -ls
3366871 439652 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random     449314816 Jun  8 07:47 storage1/bla1
3366884    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random            0 Jun  9 04:29 storage1/blass
4639952    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random            0 Jun  9 04:44 storage1/blass222122
4639950    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random            0 Jun  9 04:33 storage1/blass2221
4639951    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random            0 Jun  9 04:33 storage1/blass22212
4639953    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random            0 Jun  9 04:45 storage1/blass2221221
4639954    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random            0 Jun  9 04:47 storage1/blass22212211
4639955    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 randomUser  random            0 Jun  9 04:47 storage1/blass2221221121
```

Comment: check `man diff` and see if --suppress-common-lines i available there.

Comment: its there 

diff --suppress-common-lines -y snap1 snap2
                                                              > storage1/blass222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using bash? If so, try using bash process substitution:

```
diff --suppress-common-lines -y <(find storage1 -type f -ls) initialSnapShot.log
```

Or, if you're not using bash, try specifying it explicitly

```
bash -c 'diff --suppress-common-lines -y <(find storage1 -type f -ls) initialSnapShot.log'
```

Comment: So you're not using `bash` then. Try the suggested edit in the answer